# Subjonctif avec "il n'y a pas beaucoup ..."

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

L'expression *Il n'y a rien que* exige le subjonctif:

> Il n'y a rien que je puisse faire.

L'expression *Il n'y a pas beaucoup que* exige-t-elle le subjonctif aussi ?

> Il n'y a pas beaucoup que je puisse faire.

ou

> Il n'y a pas beaucoup que je peux faire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Il n'y a rien* entraîne le subjonctif ici parce qu'on cherche à exprimer l'éventualité d'une action et non pas une action dont la réalité est avérée. Il en va de même avec *il (n)y a (pas) beaucoup*.
Donc, oui, on dirait:

> Il n'y a pas beaucoup que je puisse faire.

Ceci dit cette phrase est correcte et compréhensible, mais personnellement je préférerais exprimer ça autrement :

> Il n'y a pas grand chose que je puisse faire.

> Il y a peu de choses que je puisse faire.

> Il n'y a pas beaucoup de choses que je puisse faire.

De même que je préfère dire :

> Il y a peu de choses que je puisse faire.

à

> Il y a peu  que je puisse faire.

C'est peut-être dû au fait que je préfère employer un nom qu'un pronom après *il y a*, et *peu* et *beaucoup* peuvent être des pronoms, alors que *rien* peut aussi être un nom en plus d'être un pronom. Dans *peu de choses* et *beaucoup de choses*, *peu* et *beaucoup* sont des adverbes.

Comment: Est-ce faut d'écrire : "il n'y a rien que je peux faire" ?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps le *que* entraîne quand même une construction avec le subjonctif, perso je n'emploierais cette construction avec *que* que si je veux employer le subjonctif, sinon pour l'indicatif je dirais :  je ne peux rien faire, il n'y a rien à faire...

Comment: Mon Dieu, "faux" bien évidemment. Merci pour ta réponse.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps On finit par rétablir automatiquement les typos dans les commentaires, je n'avais même pas vu. Moi je venais juste de m'apercevoir que j'avais écrit indicatif à la place de subjonctif et que du coup j'avais dit le contraire de ce que je voulais dire.

Answer (score 1):

Certainement:

> Il n'y a pas beaucoup que je puisse faire.

Dans *il n'y a rien* le subjonctif souligne une incertitude alors dans *il n'y a pas beaucoup* la chose va de soi.